# changing password in apache2 webserver - digest authentication

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, digest-authentication

I am trying to change password for a site, and it is using digest authentication.

I tried with the following command

```
   $ htdigest /home/micke/users/.htdigest Ideometrics guest
```

and restarted apache2 server but it is not working. 
I followed the [tutorial](http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/Apache,_Digest_Authentication) -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First u could see the contents of the htdigest password file, like;

```
$ cat /home/micke/users/.htdigest
```

And make sure the realm name is correct. If it is;
Then u should at least try;

```
$ htdigest /home/micke/users/.htdigest 'Ideometrics' 'guest'
```

or

```
$ htdigest /home/micke/users/.htdigest 'ideometrics' 'guest'
```

In any case, the realm name is case-sensitive and you should also make sure that the AuthName directive in your .htaccess is the same case-sensitive realm name.